# How can I keep Date and Time columns when I use parse_dates in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv with a few columns, including 'Date' and 'Time'. I read the csv and set the 'Date' and 'Time' columns as index.

```
import pandas as pd
data_file = 'data.csv'
data = pd.read_csv(data_file, parse_dates=[['Date', 'Time']], index_col='Date_Time', dayfirst=True)
```

This way the 'Date' and 'Time' columns get dropped. My aim is to keep them.

Another way is the following:

```
import pandas as pd
data_file = 'data.csv'
data = pd.read_csv(data_file, parse_dates=[['Date', 'Time']])
data.set_index(['Date', 'Time'], drop=False)
```

This way keeps the columns I want but it creates a multi-index.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a flag `keep_date_col` for this:

> **keep_date_col** : boolean, default `False`
>
> If `True` and `parse_dates` specifies combining multiple columns then keep the original columns.

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted. Thanks.